# I am having trouble adding text to a text box in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple text box with text inside. I have looked online but nothing has worked for me. This is my TextBox.css file

```
div.TextBox {
position: relative; 
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}

.TextBox-input {}
```

This is my TextBox.js file

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import withStyles from '../../decorators/withStyles';
import styles from './TextBox.css';

@withStyles(styles)
class TextBox {

  static propTypes = {
    maxLines: PropTypes.number
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    maxLines: 1
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TextBox">
        {this.props.maxLines > 1 ?
          <textarea {...this.props} className="TextBox-input" ref="input" key="input" rows={this.props.maxLines} /> :
          <input {...this.props} className="TextBox-input" ref="input" key="input" />}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default TextBox;
```

Comment: You're trying to add text via CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is a little out of hand.  You are specifying `position` twice for some reason, and it's not really clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you elaborate?

Regardless, I believe your issue is that you are using `position: absolute`, and you haven't specified a width or height.  Try adding `width: 100%`, `height: 100%`, and you should at least see something on the screen.

You don't always need width and height, but since absolute positioning removes the element from the normal flow of the page, the browser needs to understand where to draw it.  Sometimes you want the element to take up all the space available, and you can do that by specifying all four sides as `0` in order to "stretch" the element out:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Firstly if you're trying to add 'text' into a textbox via CSS, you can't, CSS is used for styling HTML elements.

Using something like jQuery you can generate textboxes with specified text, here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fvk2v1so/7/

[image]

A user can enter content into a text field and press "add textbox
" and it will add the text area element with that text as the value.

```
 $('.add_button').on('click', function(e){
    //When user clicks "add textbox" ensure they have added text.
    if(!$('.add_text').val().length){
        $('.error').show();
    }
    //If there is text, append textbox with text to results div.
    else{
        //Hide error message
        $('.error').hide();

        $('.results').append('<textarea class="textbox">' + $('.add_text').val() + '</textarea>')
    }
});
```

Again, not sure what you're asking specifically but hope this can help put you on the right track?